# I am trying to add components that are held in separate .js files to a new page when using Redirect from react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I am designing a simple web page that has buttons to take the user to a newly loaded page. I am not sure how I can have components appear on this new page. I have separate .js files for all of the components (ex: RideForm.js holds the code to render a functional drop down menu on the screen) So, for example if I wanted to click the button "Plan Your Trip" and have a new page loaded with the drop down menu on there, how would I add that to my code?

```
//PlanButton.js

import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import DropDownMenu from "./DropDownMenu"

class PlanButton extends React.Component {
    state = {
    redirect: false
  }
  setRedirect = () => {
    this.setState({
      redirect: true
    })
  }
  renderRedirect = () => {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to='/plan' />

    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
       <div>
        {this.renderRedirect()}
        <button onClick={this.setRedirect}>Plan Your Trip</button>
       </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PlanButton

---------------------------Separate File-----------------------------

//RideForm.js

import React from "react"

class RideForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //beginning option (can be anything)
    this.state = {value: 'Space Mountain'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

//simply a pop up window to check the result
  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your ride is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

//set up of the drop down 
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your ride:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="Pirates">Pirates</option>
            <option value="Autopia">Autopia</option>
            <option value="Haunted Mansion">Haunted Mansion</option>
            <option value="Space Mountain">Space Mountain</option>
            <option value="Splash Mountain">Splash Mountain</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default RideForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can follow the example given by [react-router's documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).

There are a couple of components you need to use:

- `Router`, to plug `react-router` with the browser's history
- `Link`, to lead the user to another route. A link is probably better than a button. You can style the link as a button though
- `Route`, to define which component to render based on the route